Count Inversion in a array
//What is an inversion of an array? Definition: for all i & j < size of array, if i < j then you have to find pair (A[i],A[j]) such that A[j] < A[i].
//Input Format
// : N = 5, array[] = {5,3,2,1,4}
// Result
// : 7
// Explanation
// : There are 7 pairs (5,1), (5,3), (5,2), (5,4),(3,2), (3,1), (2,1) and we have left 2 pairs //(2,4) and (1,4) as both are not satisfy our condition. 

`
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] arr = {5,3,2,1,4};
        int l = arr.length;
        int i = 0,count = 0,j = l-1;
        while(i < l-1)
        {
            if(j==i)
                i++;
            else if(arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                count++;
                j--;
            }
            else
                j--;
        }
        System.out.print(count);
    }
}


i have tried doing the above code in single loop but it gives error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 5
at Main.main(Main.java:14)
i don't know what's wrong , it sounds conceptually right to me during dry run.IDK!

There's no checking for j value. Eventually, when its value becomes -1 and you do arr[j], it gives you that error.

This is the perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger. Set a break point a the first line of the loop body. Run the program. For each iteration of the loop, without looking at your code, write down what you think i, j, and arr look like after the next iteration. When you expectation differs from what your program does - think about why!

Btw, you'd have 3 pairs left. You missed (3,4). Also, when you say you tried this with single loop, have you already tried this by using 2 loop? If not, then first try with two loop, then you'll understand why your logic is wrong.

I can't see the check for "if i < j then you ...", and I believe it would be simpler to use two loops (for i and for j)

There are two problems here.
First, the error you noticed occurs because you don't contain j in any way - you need to terminate the iteration of the loop once it reaches 0.
After fixing that the program won't crash anymore, but it will return the wrong answer (for the given input, it prints 4 instead of 7). This happens because once i and j meet (in the if condition), i is incremented to evaluate the next series of pairs, but j is not reset.
Put those two corrections together, and you'll get the following:
while(i < l-1 && j >= 0)
// Problem #1-^
{
    if(j==i) {
         i++;
         j = l - 1; // Problem #2
    }
    else if(arr[i] > arr[j])
    {
        count++;
        j--;
    }
    else
        j--;
}

